# Where to find a documentation on Apt return values on error?

Tags: apt, exit-status

I am looking for a list of all possible error return values in Apt (the package management tool in Linux). All I could find with `man apt` is:

> "Diagnostics apt-get returns zero on normal operation, decimal 100 on
>   error."

Does a complete list exist?

Comment: I think it means it can return only 2 values: either 0 or 100. There are no more possibilities.

Comment: Now that you say that... You are right. I haven't even assumed it could be only ok/not ok without further granularity. Thanks

Comment: I browsed the source code and commit messages but didn't find any explanation why 100 was chosen to represent error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apt` utility returns zero, 1, or 100.

The values zero or 100 are returned by the `main()` function in `cmdline/apt.cc` in [the `apt` source distribution](https://github.com/Debian/apt) by just passing on the return value of `DispatchCommandLine()` in `apt-private/private-cmndline.cc`.  The relevant code in that function is

```c
return Errors == true ? 100 : 0;
```

That is, if there were errors, return 100, otherwise return zero.

There is no comment about the value 100 in the code.

There are also a number of `exit(100)` statements in the code that will be executed for various error conditions, as well as a single `exit(1)` which will be reached if you run `apt` without any command line options or operands (this appears to be undocumented):

```
$ apt >/dev/null
$ echo $?
1
```

(I have not looked at the other `apt`-related utilities, only `apt` itself)